# Receiving Packets of specific IP

Tags: php, ip, port, packet

I have started to capture the packets sent from my PC and i am wondering how it happens that they are always going to right address.
For example i am sending message to Specific IP and Specific Port, how come nobody is faking his IP address and Port to be for example Google.com and send different response than google does.
I have read that Ddos attacks are most likely hiding their real IPs with different one, i am thinking about way of receiving packets that are sent.
Isn't there any way to listen for packets, sent to specific IP and Port?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site? This has nothing to do with programming, so it's not suited for SO.

Comment: Yes, i didn't notice that stackoverflow is only ment for programming. I will also ask in there later